# Variable sized image mapping not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code for a webpage and the mapping is not working quite right (literally - the reference points seem to be too far to the right and change as the image changes size, although I've copied and customized the code from [here](http://davidjbradshaw.com/imagemap-resizer/example/) which works perfectly).  In the folder I have two files: 'jquery.min.js' and 'imageMapResizer.min.js' both taken from the aforelinked website. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
        <HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>TODO: Enter title</TITLE>
        <Style type="text/css">
            img {width:100%; height: auto; }
            img {max-width: 500px}
            </style>

</HEAD>
<Body bgcolor="black">
<CENTER>
    <!--This table controls the upper bar section-->
<P><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=10 CELLPADDING=10>
<TR>
<TD>

    <P><a href="www.google.com">;
                    <img src="image1.png"></a>
<TD>
<P><IMG SRC="Logo.png">
<TD>
<P><a href="www.ebay.com">;
                    <img src="image2.png"></a>

</TABLE>
        <P><img src="top bar under.png">
       <p>

    <img width= "100%" border="0" usemap="#map1" src="map.png" name="map1"></img>

</p>
        <map name="map1">


    <area title="B" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="30,67,129,332" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="K" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="142,67,195,151" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="C" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="202,68,265,166" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="D" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="389,34,415,32,419,21,520,21,521,65,537,64,541,110,519,109,522,221,480,221,481,234,437,232,434,187,425,185,421,143,407,145,409,57,414,57,414,44,390,44,389,42,389,42" shape="poly"></area>
    <area title="R" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="206,195,256,312" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="X" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="168,314,299,355" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="KC" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="296,188,294,286,332,287,333,274,367,277,367,244,335,215,319,210,320,189" shape="poly"></area>
    <area title="PD" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="575,19,620,125" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="DR" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="589,283,624,423" shape="rect"></area>
    <area title="M" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" coords="447,293,573,427" shape="rect"></area>
</map>





</center>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageMapResizer.min.js"></script> 
<script>$('map1').imageMapResize();</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: BTW - I'm using Firefox if that's of any help

Comment: Could you post a fiddle please? Anyway, on a quick look - try replacing ```width=600px``` to ```width="100%"``` as per demo link?

Comment: @Varinder - sorry: what is a 'fiddle'?  Additionally, changing to width="100%" makes it even worse: it goes from being slightly off to completely off the mark

Comment: They're using a script `imageMapResizer.min.js` in their example which is handling the automatic resizing of the image with respect to the image map. You need to include this script on your page and then run `$('map').imageMapResize();` at some point after you include that script to utilize it.

Comment: @aarontam - if copying and pasting the code of the webpage wouldn't include that then no.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can place this in a few different locations, but for now you can place these lines just inside your closing </body> tag:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script>$('map').imageMapResize();</script>`

For for the first script tag, you need to update "src" to the location of your copy of imageMapResizer.min.js, which you will need to download from their website.

Comment: @aarontam I've updated the code in the question, but it's still not working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your answer to show your source, it looks like something got cut off.

Comment: @aarontam - that's the full source

Comment: @aarontam: I've changed the mapping and in normal mode (ie when the image is at 600px as maximum, it works fine.  It's now only when I reduce the size of the image to below 600px that the troubles start.  Obviously the mapping points are remaining at the same point and not changing.

Comment: @N.Soong - A `fiddle` as mentioned by Varinder, is, in this context, a  demo posted on jsfiddle.net - Link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ah sorry I swapped the order of the first two scripts when I pasted them. Can you include the jquery script first, followed by the imageMapResizer script?

Comment: @aarontam I've made the changes you specified but that still doesn't work.  The issue I raised in my last comment still stands.  Could you post an answer with my source in the post making the suggested changes, as I'm starting to get lost now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error lies in this line:

```
<script>$('map1').imageMapResize();</script>
```

which should be

```
<script>$('map').imageMapResize();</script>
```